# developing tool for building Android/Iphone app

Tags: c#, android, iphone, .net, mobile

I have .net c# background(don't mind to learn new language to get the things right). Right now i want to make some small applications for Iphone/Android phones.Basically, i will show some graphs with data retrieved through my webservice.

Can anyone tell me which developing tool should i use to create those small apps quickly?

I don't have any experience with Flash.And i just know that Flash builder 4.5 can convert Flash applications to Iphone/Android. However, i don't feel like that it is a native way to build Iphone/Android app

But if you advise that, i might go that way.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

[Xamarin](http://www.xamarin.com) has products that allows you to use **C#** (and your existing skills) for both iOS (iPhone / iPad) and Android devices : [MonoTouch](http://ios.xamarin.com) and [Mono for Android](http://android.xamarin.com).

**disclaimer:** *I work for Xamarin*

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use frameworks that help build apps for multiple platforms with the need to know native programming languages. [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) is one of these popular frameworks.

Comment: Adobe bought PhoneGap a few days ago.

Comment: I have just checked phone gap and it seems like that it doesn't have any Graph controls. My apps will be Graphs which shows data retrieving from the web service. I want to make one for iphone and android

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# to create a WCF service. There are a few different libraries to develop Android applications. If you want to work with C#, you can check out Mono for Android.

http://docs.xamarin.com/android

From my knowledge, however, Java is the preferred language to develop Android application. Eclipse has a great plugin which integrates with the Android SDK / Emulator.